# Another nginx reverse proxy issue

Tags: ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm putting together an nginx reverse proxy. Here is a working nginx conf file snippet:

```
upstream my_upstream_server {
  server 10.20.30.40:12345;
}

server {
  server_name ssl-enabled.example.com;

  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;


  location / {
      proxy_pass         http://my_upstream_server/;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
```

This allows us to serve requests from my_upstream_server without changing any of its configuration files, and in the bargain serve them up via ssl. So far so good.

What I really want to do, though, is configure this so that instead of going to https://ssl-enabled.example.com/, we can direct users to https://ssl-enabled.example.com/upstream/. (I want to do this so we can have multiple virtual hosts running, each proxying a different service that we want to ssl-enable.) I've tried changing the location line from `location /` to `location /upstream/`; when I do that, the index page of the application (https://ssl-enabled.example.com/upstream/) renders fine, but pages underneath it generate 404 errors. Here's an example:

```
This <a href="/some/link.html">link</a> is broken
```

Nginx tries to serve /some/link.html instead of /upstream/some/link.html, which doesn't work.

I tried to create a rewrite that would send the request to /upstream$1, but for the main page (which nginx now thinks is https://.../upstream/) it goes into an endless loop, tries to serve /upstream/upstream/upstream/..., and of course fails.

I suspect I'm missing something both vital and simple, but so far I haven't figured out what it might be. The documentation may provide a clue, but if it does I'm not seeing it. Any help from the nginx experts out there would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's not `nginx tries to serve`, it's you page's links broken. And it's usually hard to fix them because you have to fix them in your application, not nginx. Just stick with `/` is much better and easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config below should do a similar redirect as you mentioned without entering a loop:

```
upstream my_upstream_server {
    server 10.20.30.40:12345;
}

server {
    server_name ssl-enabled.example.com;

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;
    ssl_protocols            TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers              HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location /upstream {
        proxy_pass          http://my_upstream_server/;
        proxy_redirect      off;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://ssl-enabled.example.com/upstream$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Basically two location blocks.

One for requests starting with "upstream", which are served, and the other for those without, which are redirected.

Comment: This is very close, but it's not quite there. When I click on a (unmodified) link to /some/link.html, it serves the page properly, but the URL bar shows https://server.example.com/some/link.html (without the /upstream). But I still marked it as the accepted answer, because at least now the links aren't broken. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alexey is right about / being easier to use, and about the time he posted his comment, I came to the realization that since I can create DNS entries for example.com, instead of trying to direct people to https://server.example.com/upstream/ it would be much easier to just create a DNS entry for https://upstream.example.com/

So that's what I did and it looks like the code is doing exactly what I want. Thanks to Alexey and Dayo for their replies.